# Checking for null?

Tags: dart

In Dart we have simplified initialization of variables through the constructor:

e.g.

```dart
class Foo
{
    Bar _bar;

    Foo(this._bar);
}
```

At first glance this seems very convenient. But in my experience in 95% of the cases you would expect that what is sent in to a constructor should be non-null.

e.g. in C# I would write:

```c#
public class Foo
{
    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
         if (bar == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");

         this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

So my question is what the best-practice in Dart for null arguments is? Given that we have a language feature that basically discourages it?

Answer (score 11):

In Dart's source code they throw `ArgumentError`.
Most time they don't check for `null` but the variable type.

```dart
int codeUnitAt(int index) {
  if (index is !int) throw new ArgumentError(index);
  // ...
```

**Source:** [dart/sdk/lib/_internal/lib/js_string.dart#L17](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/lib/js_string.dart#L17)

```dart
factory JSArray.fixed(int length)  {
  if ((length is !int) || (length < 0)) {
    throw new ArgumentError("Length must be a non-negative integer: $length");
  }
  // ...
```

**Source:** [dart/sdk/lib/_internal/lib/js_array.dart#L25](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/lib/js_array.dart#L25)

Comment: That's interesting. Though a bit strange? Can length be anything other than int? Though I guess it would be consistent between typed and dynamic parameters.

Comment: @ronag It can, in unchecked mode. Types aren't enforced there.

Comment: @MarioP: Hm, are you sure? I mean types are checked at compile time. What scenario is there where something that compiles with types would result in an incorrect type in runtime?

Comment: @ronag Type "errors" are mere warnings, it still compiles fine if you ignore it. The difference is that in checked mode, type errors raise exceptions, while in unchecked mode it runs fine, until it hits a check as demonstrated in the answer. Or tries to call a nonexisting class method or something like that.

Comment: @ronag - In dart you can think of the type declarations being  like assert statements i.e. assert(length is int). These asserts are turned off in production mode - in this mode the types can be completely wrong, and the program will still run. Have a look at this [article about optional types](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/) for more background information.

Comment: How do we check for null then? I expected that if the element does not exist it must return null... Is there a way to check if threw an exception?

Answer (score 4):

This method of initialization only saves you from manually assigning the parameters, checks and other logic still requires a body. Still a useful feature, I think.

```dart
class Foo {

  var _bar;

  Foo(this._bar) {
    if(this._bar==null) throw new ArgumentError(_bar);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hm, I didn't think of that. Though I'm having a hard time with checking values after assignment. Doing something like that in a regular function would invalidate any exception guarantee. But I guess in the case of a constructor it would be ok. I find it a bit unintuitive.

Comment: Also, I find it even more unintuitive to throw an exception for an invalid argument after checking a local var value.

Comment: @ronag It's certainly a little bit uncommon, but as a very lazy person, I still like it. For me, it works as I intend - doing `f = new Foo(null);` results in `f` being NULL, even if the exception is caught and ignored.

Comment: should be throw **new** ArgumentError(_bar);

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you prefer.

The most common code is similar to the C# you show:

```dart
if (bar == null) throw new ArgumentError("arg is null");
```

It gives useful error messages, and it prevents the following code from doing something wrong (like randomly formatting hard drives on a null).

I'd write:

```dart
Foo(Bar bar) : _bar = bar {
  if (bar == null) throw ArgumentError(...);
}
```

because I find it more readable than alternatives, but if you prefer, you can even write:

```dart
Foo(Bar bar) : this.bar = bar ?? throw ArgumentError(...);
```

Using `assert(bar != null)` works fine too. It only catches the problem if assertions are enabled, but if it's just to protect yourself (e.g., on an internal class in your library) that is good enough. For public-facing functions and classes, I would prefer the if-throw.

Comment: Perhaps something like [Guava Preconditions#checkNotNull](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull%28T%29) could be useful (in [quiver](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver) ?).

Comment: `<!-- language-all: lang-dart -->` shouldn't be necessary anymore for syntax highlighting since a while.

Comment: Oooh, thanks for that info. It's not exactly a breeze to write :)

Comment: @lm If we have multiple arguments then?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem to check each parameter individually. I would just throw for the first problem found, not try to collect all problems, so it's just more of the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to "simplified initialization" as a "language feature discouragement for null checking" ... I may have misunderstood your question.

Anyway here is my approach for this:

```
class About  {

  final String title;
  final String text;

  const About({    
    customTitle,
    customText,
  }) :
    title = customTitle ?? "",
    text = customText ?? "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use assert to do your checks

[Chapter 2. A Tour of the Dart Language](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#assert)

```dart
assert(text != null);
```

> Assert statements work only in checked mode. They have no effect in production mode.

So assert is convenient for development but doesn't affect performance in production.

If you want the check to persist in production you can do as in C#

```dart
if (bar == null) {
  throw new ArgumentError('Bar must not be null');
}
```

[Exceptions - Dart Tips, Ep 9](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-9.html)

Comment: Yes, one could use an assertion if one was worried about performance. Either way using an exception or assertion does not matter to the question.

Comment: Again, I know I can use exceptions in dart. Please read the question, in particular the "best practice" and " language feature that basically discourages it".

Comment: I must admit that I then don't understand you question.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with best practice. Not every field is set by an constructor parameter. You can provide a default value on the field or on the constructor parameter or calculate the value in the constructor and assign it to the field.

Comment: I haven't seen any "best practice" guides for this particular example. What I'd do is use runtime null checks and exceptions for important public APIs. And for other methods just use assert statements, or nothing. I don't think you can come up with a one-size fits all rule.  I have seen comments suggesting that checking types at runtime is generally the wrong thing to do. I.e. if (foo is! String) throw new Boom();

Comment: There is also talk about adding [non-nullable types](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22) to the language. This was delayed to post 1.0, an ECMA standards committee is being set up where language changes can be discussed.